# Multiple Git accounts to use with terminal and GitKraken on Mac

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I am trying to set my Mac environment with 2 different GitHub accounts and I want to be able to execute git commands using either GitKraken and Terminal.

I know how to set both but individually:

1. If I use GitKraken, I create 2 profiles:

[image]

2. If I don't use GitKraken, I modify my ~/.ssh/config file

The issue I am facing is that if I try to combine both, One works but not the other.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Yea this is really frustrating, for me when I add a custom github host in .ssh/config and add that as the remote for a repo, gitkraken just doesn't fetch (endless spinner) =\